# template template parameter causing compiler error in clang

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a template that is compiling fine in MSVC (2017) but fails in clang (4.0):

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <template <typename U, U, U> class, typename, typename>
struct meta_zip;

template <template <typename U, U, U> class OP, typename TA, TA... As, typename TB, TB... Bs>
struct meta_zip<OP, std::integer_sequence<TA, As...>, std::integer_sequence<TB, Bs...>>
{
    using common_type = typename std::common_type<TA, TB>::type;

    using type = std::integer_sequence<common_type, OP<common_type, As, Bs>::value...>;
};

template <template <typename U, U, U > class OP, typename A, typename B>
using meta_zip_t = typename meta_zip<OP, A, B>::type;

namespace impl
{

template <typename T, T A, T B>
using meta_zip_add = std::integral_constant<T, (A + B)>;

}

template <typename A, typename B>
using meta_zip_add = meta_zip<impl::meta_zip_add, A, B>;

template <typename A, typename B>
using meta_zip_add_t = typename meta_zip_add<A, B>::type;

template <int width>
class blend_low
{
private:
    using counter1 = std::make_integer_sequence<int, 3>;
    using counter2 = std::make_integer_sequence<int, 3>;

public:
    using value = meta_zip_add_t<counter1, counter2>;
};

int main()
{
    static constexpr auto foo = blend_low<4>::value();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm reasonably new to templates and don't know how to rework `OP` to make it work. I've tried `OP<U, U, U>` but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What Clang version?

Comment: As an aside, I'd use a stateless constexpr functor instead of `meta_zip_add`, like `struct add{ tempate<class T, class U> constexpr auto operator()(T const& t, U const& u)const { return t+u; } constexpr add() {} };`

Comment: Seems to work in clang++5 but fail in clang++4. Probably a clang bug

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo, yes it's clang 4, is there any work around, I'm stuck on clang 4 :-(

Comment: [Obvious bug is obvious](https://godbolt.org/g/brv1F7).

Comment: @Yakk, thanks, this idea has provided me with a workaround